# C# Parallel.ForEach throw IndexOutOfBounds but foreach does not?

Tags: c#, parallel-foreach

My program must check the state of all elements in array. When I use `foreach` it's ok, but in `Parallel.ForEach` and `Parallel.For` it throws index out of bounds exception.

This code works:

```
foreach (var p in _currentSpherePoints)
{
    point = p + center;
    point.X = (point.X + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.X)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.X);
    point.Y = (point.Y + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Y)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Y);
    point.Z = (point.Z + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Z)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Z);
    if (_field[point.X, point.Y, point.Z] != 0)
    {
        isCrossed = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

And this not:

```
Parallel.ForEach(_currentSpherePoints, (p, state) =>
{
    point = p + center;
    point.X = (point.X + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.X)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.X);
    point.Y = (point.Y + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Y)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Y);
    point.Z = (point.Z + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Z)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Z);
    if (_field[point.X, point.Y, point.Z] != 0)
    {
        isCrossed = true;
        state.Stop();
    }
});
```

```
public bool IsSphereCrossed(VectorInt center)
{
    bool isCrossed = false;
    var point = new VectorInt(0, 0, 0);

    Parallel.ForEach(_currentSpherePoints, (p, state) =>
    {
        point = p + center;
        point.X = (point.X + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.X)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.X);
        point.Y = (point.Y + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Y)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Y);
        point.Z = (point.Z + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Z)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Z);
        if (_field[point.X, point.Y, point.Z] != 0)
        {
            isCrossed = true;
            state.Stop();
        }
    });
    return isCrossed;
}
```

As you see, I don't change collection, so I don't know, where there is a problem.
`_currentSpherePoints` contains my own Vector class.

Comment: At which line does the exception occur? Are the data identical in both code?

Comment: At line: 
if (_field[point.X, point.Y, point.Z] != 0)
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

But x, y and z doesn't cross bounds and every time they have different values

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint there and see why the values of X, Y and Z cause it?

Comment: They different every time

Comment: My guess is that you were lucky with the data, so `foreach` run in sequence and `break` occurs before it meets the point that has the problem. But for `Parallel`, the data is not guaranteed to be run in sequence so you encounter the problematic point before `Stop` occurs.

Comment: For example, array has 100;100;100 dimensions and it as thrown on 25, 5 and 78 respectively

Comment: That's impossible, could you share the data or a reproducible code please?

Comment: I shared all class code. Thank you!
Data is float array, consisting of 1, 0 and -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have shared the whole function, here's the problem:

```cs
    public bool IsSphereCrossed(VectorInt center)
    {
        bool isCrossed = false;
        var point = new VectorInt(0, 0, 0); // This variable is changed randomly

        Parallel.ForEach(_currentSpherePoints, (p, state) =>
        {
            point = p + center;
            point.X = (point.X + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.X)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.X);
            point.Y = (point.Y + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Y)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Y);
            point.Z = (point.Z + _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Z)) % _field.GetLength((int)VectorInt.Dimension.Z);
            if (_field[point.X, point.Y, point.Z] != 0)
            {
                isCrossed = true;
                state.Stop();
            }
        });
        return isCrossed;
    }
```

Notice `point` variable is **shared** between all runs of `Parallel.ForEach`, which you can't be sure to be the same for *each whole* run. For example, in one thread, `point` may be assigned a value, and then the context switch to run with another `p` and `point` is reassigned to another value and when the thread for previous `p` is back, `point` no longer has the correct value.

You need to ensure it's immutable, probably by declaring it inside `Parallel.ForEach`.